# PHP Page is not Sending Email

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, email

I have a page that has a form for the user to input their email into. Once the form is submitted the email gets checked in my MSSQL table and if it exists in one of the table's rows it will send an email to the user's email. Right now, I correctly put in an existing email and the email is never received. I am trying to make this so that if the user forgets their password, it will retrieve the password from the correct row and send that password to the user's email.

Here is my PHP page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$conn=mssql_connect('gdm','dr','Rd1!');
mssql_select_db('Gdr',$conn);
if (isset($_POST['forgotpass'])) {
$conn=mssql_connect('gdom','GBdr','d1!');
mssql_select_db('Gdr',$conn);
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);

    }

 $email = $_POST['email'];
$querye = "SELECT password FROM staffportal WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
$check = mssql_query($querye, $conn);
$check2 = mssql_num_rows($check);
echo "".$check2."";
//if the email doesn't exist it gives an error
 if ($check2 != 0) {
print"<p>Thank you, dsa we will get back to you.</p>";
print"<p>Today's date isdsa.</p>";
    ob_start();
     $tae = "".$_POST['email']."";  
     echo "".$tae."";
    $out2 = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
var_dump($out2);
var_dump($out2); 
$to = "".$out2."";
echo "Emailing to: ".$to."";
$subject = "Financing fordsac ";
$body = "dsdasd \n\n";
$headers = "From: info@gbmtd.ca";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
} else {
    echo "Sorry, the email ".$email." is incorrect.";
} } else {
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
      Email:<br />
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
 <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" id="forgotpass" value="Change Password" name="forgotpass"/>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This gets displayed on my page after I hit submit:

```
1
Thank you, dsa we will get back to you.

Today's date isdsa.

string(22) "kelseynealon@gmail.com" string(22) "kelseynealon@gmail.com" Emailing to: kelseynealon@gmail.com
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help.

Comment: use `$to = $_POST['email'];` instead of  `$to = "".$out2."";`

Comment: Storing passwords in clear text in a database is a very bad idea.

Comment: Your `$to` is basically trying to send mail to everything inside `ob_get_contents()` why not just do the regular *run of the mill* `$to = "email@example.com";` to test.

Comment: What does mail() return? It returns FALSE on failure. See docs. Also you need port 25 to be open in the firewall of the server in order for the mail to work.

Comment: Krish, that does not work, as I have tried it. Thanks for that nugget of wisdom, Tim. I am doing that now, Fred, to test it. Fibbe, I used this `$mail = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo "Mail: ".$mail."";` and recieved `Mail: 1` when running the page. Also, I have mail functions on other parts of my website that work so I don't understand what the problem is to be honest.

Comment: You can also try using `$to = $email`; see if that makes it kick in. Plus, as already stated, storing passwords in plain text is not safe and should not be used. Password resetting is a better option and using `crypt()` or PHP 5.5's `password_hash()` function. "Forgot password" is a much more complicated process. It's just a matter of time before your site gets (*heaven forbid*) hacked.

Comment: It appears none of my mail functions are working. Even on the pages that were previously working.

Comment: Have you tried using just a simple form to see if `mail()` is in fact working or not? That will tell you right away. @Michael Or, you know this to be the actual issue?

Comment: Yes I have, and the mail function does not send the email. The function used to send emails, too. So maybe someone altered the mail settings for the website. I also have a theory that the website server may just be down, in terms of sending mail via PHP.

Comment: Ok. I for one use a few backup servers when something goes all weirdly. If possible, try and setup another server and exporting your SQL as `.sql` then importing them back into the new one, where you know `mail()` is in fact functioning. @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had mixed luck with the PHP mail function.  You can take a gander at the PHP mail function page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php to look for clues.  Personally I use PHP SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org/) for any email sending from PHP applications and it works really well.

Here's a generic function I have for using it:

```
/*
Starting code for sending email via this function:
list($email_logger, $email_mailer) = email_interface();
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setFrom(array('from@domain.ext' => 'John Doe'))
        ->setTo(array('to@domain.ext' => 'Jane Doe'))
        ->setSubject('<SUBJECT>')
        ->setBody('<BODY>');
$email_mailer->send($message);
*/

// Returns PHP SwiftMailer mailer and logger email interfaces
function email_interface()
{

        // Mail configuration
        $global_email_config = array(
                //'relay_encryption' => 'ssl',
                //'relay_host' => 'relayhost.domain.ext',
                //'relay_port' => '465',
                // 'relay_user' => '<ADDR>',
                // 'relay_pass' => '<PASS>',
                'smtp_sender' => array(
                        'sender@domain.ext' => 'Sender Name'
                )
        );

        if (isset($global_email_config['relay_host'])) {
                $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();
                $transport->setHost($global_email_config['relay_host']);

                if (isset($global_email_config['relay_port'])) {
                        $transport->setPort($global_email_config['relay_port']);
                }

                if (isset($global_email_config['relay_encryption'])) {
                        $transport->setEncryption($global_email_config['relay_encryption']);
                }

                if (isset($global_email_config['relay_user'])) {
                        $transport->setUsername($global_email_config['relay_user']);
                        $transport->setPassword($global_email_config['relay_pass']);
                }

        } else {
                $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance();
        }

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
        $mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

        return array(
                $logger,
                $mailer
        );
}
```